# Redis Make Test fails on Raspberry Pi Zero W with Raspbian

Tags: makefile, redis, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

I've been trying to install Redis on my Raspberry Pi Zero W running Raspbian Buster. I downloaded the latest and ran Make, which went fine, but when I run "make test," it fails under "Testing integration/replication" and then crashes my Pi so I have to reboot it. I've tried this several times and it always goes that same way. I'm nervous about running make install at this point because this test keeps failing.

I am also running MariaDB, Wordpress, PostgreSQL, and Timetrex with nginx if that gives any sense of my current RAM usage.

Is there any way to get it to pass the test?

This is where it stops, during test 27:

```
[26/64 done]: integration/block-repl (27 seconds)
Testing integration/replication
[ok]: Slave enters handshake
[ok]: Slave is able to detect timeout during handshake
[ok]: Set instance A as slave of B
[ok]: INCRBYFLOAT replication, should not remove expire
[ok]: GETSET replication
[ok]: BRPOPLPUSH replication, when blocking against empty list
[ok]: BRPOPLPUSH replication, list exists
[ok]: BLMOVE (left, left) replication, when blocking against empty list
[ok]: BLMOVE (left, left) replication, list exists
[ok]: BLMOVE (left, right) replication, when blocking against empty list
[ok]: BLMOVE (left, right) replication, list exists
[ok]: BLMOVE (right, left) replication, when blocking against empty list
[ok]: BLMOVE (right, left) replication, list exists
[ok]: BLMOVE (right, right) replication, when blocking against empty list
[ok]: BLMOVE (right, right) replication, list exists
[ok]: BLPOP followed by role change, issue #2473
[ok]: Second server should have role master at first
[ok]: SLAVEOF should start with link status "down"
[ok]: The role should immediately be changed to "replica"
[ok]: Sync should have transferred keys from master
[ok]: The link status should be up
[ok]: SET on the master should immediately propagate
[ok]: FLUSHALL should replicate
[ok]: ROLE in master reports master with a slave
[ok]: ROLE in slave reports slave in connected state
[ok]: Connect multiple replicas at the same time (issue #141), master diskless=no, replica diskless=disabled
[ok]: Connect multiple replicas at the same time (issue #141), master diskless=no, replica diskless=swapdb
[ok]: Connect multiple replicas at the same time (issue #141), master diskless=yes, replica diskless=disabled
[ok]: Connect multiple replicas at the same time (issue #141), master diskless=yes, replica diskless=swapdb
[ok]: Master stream is correctly processed while the replica has a script in -BUSY state
[ok]: slave fails full sync and diskless load swapdb recovers it
[ok]: diskless loading short read
[TIMEOUT]: clients state report follows.
sockd58378 => (SPAWNED SERVER) pid:24500
Killing still running Redis server 24477
Killing still running Redis server 24489
Killing still running Redis server 24500
```

I looked for an error code but found only this:

```
!!! WARNING The following tests failed:

*** [TIMEOUT]: clients state report follows.
Cleanup: may take some time... OK
make[1]: *** [Makefile:391: test] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/redis-stable/src'
make: *** [Makefile:6: test] Error 2
```

It doesn't say *which* tests failed, so I don't even know what to Google at this point.

Comment: Did you look at line 391 in `/home/pi/redis-stable/src/Makefile`?

Comment: test: $(REDIS_SERVER_NAME) $(REDIS_CHECK_AOF_NAME) $(REDIS_CLI_NAME) $(REDIS$        @(cd ..; ./runtest)

Comment: This part: `$(REDIS$ @(cd ..; ./runtest)` is probably wrong. It does not look like make syntax.

Comment: Should I... change it somehow? Delete the folder and restart the Make process from scratch? I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: Restarting from scratch will change something only if this syntax error is an accidental modification of the original Makefile. Else, the error will be the same. You should edit your question and show the complete rule of the `test` target (the line starting with `test:` and the following ones with a leading tab. Pay attention to the formatting, it is extremely important in Makefiles. Once we will see the complete rule we will maybe be able to suggest something (not 100% sure, we may need more information).

Comment: I think I'm officially out of my depth here. I don't think I understand what you're asking for.